# software that can edit text and have good graphics layout tools

Tags: pdf, forms, microsoft-word

I'm helping some colleagues design some 8.5x11 signs, I've done these in Illustrator and exported as PDF. Problem is my colleagues don't have Illustrator nor Adobe Acrobat, but they need to be able to edit a bit of text on it (very minor, in fact it's just a date). All they have is Word and Adobe Reader pretty much (company computers).

What would be the best format to hand over to my colleagues? I don't think I can recreate my entire design in Word as a) its formatting will mess up depending on what version of Word they're using and b) it probably can't handle some layouts. Adobe PDF forms? It might work but the fill-able fields are just so damn ugly and does not match my fonts at all.

Comment: This probably isn't the best way to do this but could you export the pdf as an image, give them the font, include the image in a word document without the date, and have them in the word document add a text field setting the same font you gave them and type in the date?

Answer (score 1):

From what your headline says, I was thinking of [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/) right away. Ever heard about this? It's free and open source and runs on all major OS's (Linux, Windows, OSX).

Inkscape is a comprehensive vector graphics tool. You can either exchange the native *.svg file with your colleagues, who might import it into MS Word or MS PowerPoint. Or you might try any of the available export formats such as *.wmf (Windows meta file) or *.emf (Extended meta file).